# rotation angles in fovis odometry

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, fovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am going to use fovis to do visual odometry. The obtained geometry information will be used for 2D mapping.

For 2D mapping, what I want is the horizontal rotation, ie the rotation along y-axis(downward). In fovis, I obtain the 3d rotation, but I am confused.

I ran the example program in libfovis with kinect, these codes return the odometry information:
Eigen::Vector3d xyz = cam_to_local.translation();
Eigen::Vector3d rpy = cam_to_local.rotation().eulerAngles(0, 1, 2);

I am not sure about the type of rotation of rpy is.
As I tested with kinect, I guess rpy(1) gives me the horizontal rotation angle, but its range is just +/- 90 degrees. What kind of transformation I need if I want the range to be +/- 180 degrees? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55224/rotation-angles-in-fovis-odometry/) by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on 2013-02-14**:
There is the example program I ran: http://fovis.googlecode.com/git/libfovis/examples/fv-example-openni/               .
The codes I quoted is in main.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rpy represents the roll, pitch and yaw angles. Assuming that the x axis points forward, the y axis to the left and the z axis upwards, then roll is rotation about the x axis, pitch is rotation about the y axis and yaw is rotation about the  axis. In your case you want the pitch angle. a pitch angle of 90 degrees means your pointing the camera upwards, and -90 means its pointing downwards.

May I ask, are you using the fovis_ros wrapper? If so, how did you get it to work with the Kinect (because aparently the fovis_ros wrapper does not support the kinect yet but only stereo vision)?

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on 2013-02-14**:
I am not actually using fovis_ros wrapper. I found your quesetion about making the fovis work with kinect. See if my answer can help you at http://answers.ros.org/question/54148/fovis-fatal-error-linuxcompilerh-no-such-file-or-directory/

**Comment by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on 2013-02-14**:
Follow your assumption of axis, I want the yaw angle.

Actually, there is description about the axis in fovis: +Z pointing along the camera look vector, +X to the right, and +Y down. But there is no description about the angles.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-02-14**:
Then roll angle is about the Z axis, pitch angle is about the X-axis and yaw angle about the Y-axis.Thanks for your answer on my other question. I will give it a try.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-02-14**:
Since yesterday fovis_ros supports kinect RGBD input in fovis_ros wrapper.

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-02-15**:
Thanks Miquel, I will give a try.